# Send KeyEventArgs to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way we can send the keydown events to the Javascript function as its parameters, In Silverlight4 ??

Comment: Darn!! , I PITY the poor community support of Silverlight :(

Answer (score 0):

If it's only the value being entered into the textbox that you want to send to your javascript function then you could use something akin to this:

```
    private void textbox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("keyPressFunction", new object[] { e.Key.ToString() });
    }
```

Hope this helps!